# UNIX shell script error - syntax error near unexpected token `if'

Tags: shell, unix, syntax, command

I am getting error "syntax error near unexpected token `if'" while executing the shell script.

Could someone help me find out if I am doing some mistake syntactically.

```
if [ date "+%b %d" == ls -lrt start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f6-7 ] &&
   [ date "+%k" == ls -lrt start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8 | cut -c1-2 ] &&
   [ ls -lrt start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8 | cut -c4-5 >= date -d "now 15 minutes ago" "+%M" ]; then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use command substitutions to capture the output of the commands for comparison.

```
if [ $(date "+%b %d") = $(ls -lrt start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f6-7) ] &&
    # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am still getting the same error.         if [ $(date "+%b %d") = $(ls -lrt ../servers/logs/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f6-7) ] && [ $(date "+%k") = $(ls -lrt ../servers/logs/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8 | cut -c1-2) ] && [ $(ls -lrt ../servers/logs/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8 | cut -c4-5) >= $(date -d "now 15 minutes ago" "+%M") ]; then

Comment: Actually, if the `if` is the unexpected token, your error precedes the code you posted. `bash` is parsing some other statement that hasn't been properly closed when it encounters the keyword `if`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got that issue resolved, but I can see new error now- syntax error near unexpected token `==' and syntax error near unexpected token `$(date -d "now 15 minutes ago" "+%M")'                                                             if [ $`(date "+%b %d") == $(ls -lrt ~/servers/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f6-7)` ] &&
[ $`(date "+%k") == $(ls -lrt ~/servers/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8 | cut -c1-2)` ] &&
[ $`(ls -lrt ~/servers/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8 | cut -c4-5) >= $(date -d "now 15 minutes ago" "+%M")` ]; then

Comment: What shell are you using? `bash` allows `==` to be used inside `[ ... ]`, but that's an extension to the POSIX specification, which mandates `=`.

Comment: `ksh` should allow `==` as well; the code in the comments is too garbled to tell what you are actually running; I'll add what should be a working command to my answer.

Comment: Here is the code --      if [ $(date "+%b %d") == $(ls -lrt ~/servers/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f6-7) ] && [ $(date "+%k") == $(ls -lrt ~/servers/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8 | cut -c1-2) ] && [ $(ls -lrt ~/servers/start.log | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f8 | cut -c4-5) >= $(date -d "now 15 minutes ago" "+%M") ]; then

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure why `==` would be unexpected. However, `>=` will eventually cause an error, because there is no `>=` operator for some reason (seems like there should be if `>` and `=(=)` both exist).